# The machine name of custom view

Tags: 7, views

I created my own view thanks to Views module. How can I check the machine name of that view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display/edit the machine name for a View?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14385/how-do-i-display-edit-the-machine-name-for-a-view)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the edit screen for your view. At the top right, just under **Displays** you will see a button labelled *Edit view/name/description* (right under the Save and Cancel buttons). This is a drop down. Click on it and choose *export view*.

The second item in the export is the machinr name of the view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'your_view_name';
$view->description = ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you.

- In Drupal 7 if you want to know whats your view MACHINE name.

To get **VIEWS machine name**

- Edit your **VIEW**, in the **URL** you can see machine name 
  `sitename/admin/structure/views/view/machine_name/edit`

To get **Display Machine Name**

- Go to **VIEWS > ADVANCED TAB > Machine Name**

  [image]

Comment: To avoid confusion, that is the machine name of the _display_, and will be different for different display modes for the view.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also hover over the 'edit' button for the view in the views list (admin/structure/views) to see the view machine name in a browser tooltip - may be a little easier than exporting the view?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to check that is used machine_name was using the following function for an a page:

```
$current_view = views_get_page_view();
$machine_name_current = $current_view->current_display;
print $machine_name_current;
```

Saludos.